# Is there any sample for android-proximity-reference?

Tags: ibeacon-android

In github, android-ibeacon-reference is eclipse project, but however, android-proximity-reference is not.
Is there any sample for eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created an Eclipse version in a branch.  See:  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-proximity-reference/tree/eclipse

In order to get this to build in Eclipse, you will need to have the AndroidProximityLibrary downloaded and also set in your workspace.  You will need to change the project settings in the android-proximity-reference project to point to the library, as shown in the following dialog.  You can see more detailed setup instructions [here.](http://www.proximitykit.com/android-download)

[image: Android configuration]

Comment: for the free version library, is it open source??

Comment: also, is there any doc for pro library?

Comment: Yes, the free version library has an Apache open source license.  The main documentation for the Pro version includes a link to a comparison of the two.  You can find it here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/documentation.html

Comment: @davidgyoung  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-proximity-reference/tree/eclipse i'm trying to add that as library to my project but it is still asking library project so what i need to add as library.